# How to add a password policy on OpenLDAP 2.4.11?

Tags: debian, ldap, openldap

I have a server with OpenLDAP 2.4.11 installed.

I'm trying to add a password policy for all my users.

So, I enable ppolicy module :

```
bash# grep ppolicy /etc/ldap/slapd.conf
include         /etc/ldap/schema/ppolicy.schema
moduleload  ppolicy.la
overlay ppolicy
ppolicy_default "cn=default,ou=pwpolicies,dc=myapp,dc=fr"
```

I create a ldappolicy.ldif file :

```
dn: ou=pwpolicies,dc=myapp,dc=fr
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: pwpolicies

dn: cn=default,ou=pwpolicies,dc=myapp,dc=fr
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: default
pwdMaxAge: 2592000
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdExpireWarning: 2592000
pwdInHistory: 0
pwdCheckQuality: 1
pwdMaxFailure: 0
pwdLockout: FALSE
pwdLockoutDuration: 0
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdMustChange: FALSE
pwdMinLength: 12
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
```

I add it :

```
ldapadd -x -h myserver.fr -D 'cn=admin,dc=myapp,dc=fr' -w password  -f ldappolicy.ldif
```

But when I tried to put a password of 4 characters on a user, it continues to work :

```
ldappasswd -x -h myserver.fr -D cn=RandomUserLogin,ou=Users,dc=myapp,dc=fr -w oldPasswordOfTheUser -s test
```

I tried to follow others tutorials, but each time, I have a new problem.
For example, it seems I have to enable "ppolicy-module".

So I create a ppolicy-module.ldif file :

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changeType: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: ppolicy
```

When I tried to use it, I have insufficient access error :

```
bash# ldapmodify -x -h myserver.fr -D cn=admin,dc=myapp,dc=fr -w password -f ppolicy-module.ldif

ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)
```

So, I enable ldapi access, because I'm root on the server so I can.
Then, I tried :

```
sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ppolicy-module.ldif
```

But same error :

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=module{0},cn=config"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)
```

In some others tutorial, I find some mentions of files in :

```
/etc/ldap/slapd.d/
```

like :

```
/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif
```

But in my case, I don't have any slapd.d directory